# "Enabled For Mobile" disabled for Order Entity in CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

For some reason the "Enable for Mobile" checkbox is disabled on the Order Entity.
Would anyone know if this out of the box entity is not available for view on the Dynamics CRM for Mobile app?

Comment: CRM Online or On-Prem?